# Django: Where is the personal info form located?

Tags: django

I can't seem to locate the personal info form that's used in the admin. I am talking about the form containing first_name, last_name and email address when you click on a user.

I've been browsing the source code for 30 minutes now mostly checking out auth and admin but it seems it's not in either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py`](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L47)

```
def UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
...
```

Comment: Are the first_name, last_name, email fields defined somewhere else?

Comment: It's a model form based on the `User model` (see `class Meta: model = User` (line 52)) so all fields are retrieved from that model.